# Is it possible to open up this particular convolution equation?

Tags: filters, convolution, fourier, matched-filter

I have three vectors, $x[n]$, $w[n]$, and $z[n]$. I need to compute:

$y[n] = z[n] * \Big(x[n] \cdot w[n] \Big)$.

This is easy to do. However, is there a way I can do this by 'opening' up the bracket?

For example, let us say that I am already given $z[n] * x[n]$. If this was the starting point, what could I do with this and with the three already given vectors to get $y[n]$? The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) on convolution properties does not seem to have a case for a scenario like this.

Comment: Are there any specifics about the vectors? When the vectors $x$ and $w$ have a special form there is a way to approximate $y$ with a series of convolutions. I saw this idea in bilateral filtering.

Comment: @visoft Hmm, well you may consider $w[n]$ as a symmetric vector of length $N$. Also, both $x[n]$ and $w[n]$ are of the same length. ($N$).

Comment: Convolutions don't really play nicely with multiplications - Fourier switches convolution to multiplication and vice versa, but when you have both, you aren't exactly in a good shape for simplifying things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-write of a previously mistaken answer:

Let us write $y[n] = z[n] * \Big(x[n] \cdot w[n] \Big) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=-M}^{M} {z[n-m] \cdot (x[m] \cdot w[m])}$ and rearrange as $y[n] = \displaystyle\sum_{m=-M}^{M} {(z[n-m] \cdot x[m]) \cdot (w[m])}$. After this point, we cannot take the terms out of the brackets.